# offline browsing for moodle

Tags: php, plugins, moodle

Here in srilanka we don't have much internet facilities, we are using Moodle in our universities,but when we go home there is no way to browse the net, so my question is, is there any capability of moodle to be browsed offline??  my idea is to develop such component to be able to download the necessary files for course module and browse it offline in our homes? where should i start if i'm developing such kind of thing? i'm referring the moodle documentation now.. [moodle documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development)

please guide me on this, because it will be helpful to lots and lots of university students here in srilanka!

regards,
Rangana

Comment: Not really a programming question, so try the moodle support forums and not stack overflow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your information i'm publising what i have found, there is a website called http://www.jolongo.net/ , where offline browsing for moodle is available , here it uses Adobe AIR

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Gears for offline browsing.

Offline Moodle: Google Gears caching
http://moodle.org/mod/data/view.php?d=13&rid=2636&filter=1